# Best way to count number of "White Blobs" in a Thresholded IplImage in OpenCV 2.3.0

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, blobs

I need to count the number of white blobs in a Thresholded image. I'm counting small squares on a marker. But due to the poor image quality of the webcam, these squares don't appear as squares. This is why I decided to use Blob detection. This is for an Augmented reality application. Is my decision right?

Camera placed near the marker

[image]

Camera placed far from the marker

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

What about the `cvFindContours` function? It's been a while since I've used it, but I think you can then iterate in the CvSeq of found contours and work with them the way you like.

I know it's an old thread but maybe it can help you!

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib). This detects connected regions which you should easily be able to count, and obtain further information such as their size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed those steps. But Build failed due to various errors. 1) im on OpenCV2.3, Visual C++ 2008 and it requires cxtypes.h which is not found on my machine. I used types_c.h instead 2) cvBlobsLib requires afx.h and afxwin.h. Again, not found! :(

Comment: I have just come across the following page which discusses blob detection, and the various libraries available: http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/blobs.html Perhaps it will be of some use to you?

Answer (score 1):

I have used findContours function. 
Here is the piece of code:

```
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;      

    cv::findContours(m, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { 
        if( contours[i].size() < 3  ) // at least a triangular area?
            continue;

        double area = cv::contourArea(Mat(contours[i]) );
        if ( (area > min * min) && ( area < max * max ) )
        {
           //... use or count blob
```